# Fresh Windows 10 Education gives Inaccessible Boot Device

Tags: windows-10, bsod

I did a fresh installation of *Windows 10 Education* on my desktop PC's SSD, and as soon as the setup has finished and reboots, the newly installed Windows 10 throws me to a blue screen with the error *Inaccessible Boot Device*.

Initially my installation was a UEFI installation, but I also tried a legacy BIOS installation. I've tried reseting the BIOS settings to their defaults. I've tried setting the UEFI CSM (Compatibility Support Module) to UEFI only. There were no recovery options, and I also chkdsk-ed the SSD. All to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by repeatedly installing Windows:

> Install Windows 10 Home or Professional instead of Education, and upgrade to Education after installation.

If I install either Windows 10 Home or Professional instead of Education, the installation succeeds both in UEFI and in BIOS mode. After that go to the System control panel, click the link to *Activate Windows* and enter the Windows 10 Education product code. It will upgrade the installation, after which it finally *does* work.

Comment: After 5 hours of failing to install Windows 10 I found this post, thank you! I could kill Microsoft atm ...

Answer (score 0):

I had issues starting Windows 10 Educational after freshly installing it because the USB stick I used for booting and installing wasn't configured correctly (I think). My anti virus software always interfered when creating the boot-stick, so it didn't work with the Windows Media Creation Tool. It worked afterwards when turning of the anti virus.